# How to call an async cleanup function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

How can I call an async cleanup function in useEffect?

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return () => Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
  }, []);
```

The EffectCallback expects `void`, not `Promise<void>`

Comment: Then just don't return anything from it. Currently you're returning the Promise (because the function body is not wrapped in braces).

Comment: You can also use the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) if you don't want the extra lines/braces: `return () => void Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the body in curly braces, because currently it returns the `Promise` (this is what happens when you omit the curly braces, a one line return), which makes your cleanup function return a `Promise<void>`. With curly braces, it will be just the body of the function and not an implied return statement:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
           Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners)
        };
  }, []);
```